# Why the function works well line by line but give me error when I use it?

Tags: r, purrr

Here is my code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggrepel)
library(readxl)
test=function(a){
  f=as.character(c(a,a))
  b="g"
  D=data.frame(A=c("a","b","c"),B=c(1:3))
  E=list(D,D)
  print(f)
    assign(b,map(E,subset, A %in% f))
    g
}
```

If I run the function in this way

```
a="a"
test(a)
# output below
#[1] "a" "a"
#Error in `map()`:
#ℹ In index: 1.
#Caused by error:
#! object 'f' not found
#Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The f is definitely there because before it goes to the assign(), it printed f.
However, when I run this function line by line like this:

```
  a="a"
  f=as.character(c(a,a))
  b="g"
  D=data.frame(A=c("a","b","c"),B=c(1:3))
  E=list(D,D)
  print(f)
    assign(b,map(E,subset, A %in% f))
    g
#output below
#> g
#[[1]]
#  A B
#1 a 1
#
#[[2]]
#  A B
#1 a 1
```

No error happens if I run any single line. However, if I run the function again without clean the environment, the function would not show any error anymore.

```
#> a="a"
#> f=as.character(c(a,a))
#> b="g"
#> D=data.frame(A=c("a","b","c"),B=c(1:3))
#> E=list(D,D)
#> print(f)
#> assign(b,map(E,subset, A %in% f))
#> g
#created the objects in environment 
test(a)
#output below
#[1] "a" "a"
#[[1]]
#  A B
#1 a 1
#
#[[2]]
#  A B
#1 a 1
```

However, if I clean the environment the error will show up agian.

```
> remove(f)
> test(a)
#output below
#[1] "a" "a"
#Error in `map()`:
#ℹ In index: 1.
#Caused by error:
#! object 'f' not found
#Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Why this happened and how to fix it?

I want to subset a series of data.frames in a list by matching the elements in a vector f and use assign() to give a series of variables (defined by b) the result of the subset().

Comment: As explained in its documentation, the `subset()` function is not suited for programming, only for interactive usage. You can work around this, but doing so is cumbersome and usually not worth it. Use other, direct ways of subsetting your data instead of `subset()` (i.e. `[…]`).

Comment: Another comment: even though your code is quite short, it is ***really** hard to read!* Using meaningful variable names would drastically improve this. I get that this is a toy example, but still.

Comment: It would work if you used the tidyverse equivalent of `filter` rather than `subset` `map(E, filter, A %in% f)`

Comment: If you are beginner, you should forget that the `assign` function exists. I've been using R for more than 10 years and I have never had a valid use case for that function in production code. If you believe you need this function, you almost certainly should redesign your approach.